# How to Scrape .aspx website with requests python

Tags: python, asp.net, ssl, python-requests, get

I'm trying this simple line of code

```
import requests

url = "https://www.petplanet.co.uk"

p=requests.get(url).text

print(p)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.petplanet.co.uk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

The site is build in .apsx and that may be the dificulty.
I also tried adding headers but that didn't change anything.
I've tried this from WINDOWS and MacOS.

I also tried adding this to the code

```
p=requests.get(url, verify=False).text
```

But that didn't help either.
Also I read somewhere that this could bring some security issues.

I hope someone can help or have a solution for this

Thanks!

Comment: "The site is build in .apsx and that may be the dificulty." No it has nothing to do with that because you are not even connecting to the site as you have a TLS error. The website gave you a certificate that you can't validate (and DO NOT do `verify=False` everyone considering this is the solution to any problem doesn't understand either the problem nor the solution) because your system doesn't have the relevant CA. You are not specifiying any version of. what you are using (OS, Python, etc.) nor what results do you have if you try on same box with another tool (curl, wget, httpie, etc.)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I'm really sorry I don't have the skills :(, do I need to specify that on the request line? 
Is there a simple solution ?